# Xquery transform error "Invalid coercion () as document-node()"

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I'm trying to transform my search results into some-other format using XQuery. I'm using example XQuery transformation as in documentation like:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
module namespace example = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/add-attr";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";


declare function example:transform(
  $context as map:map,
  $params as map:map,
  $content as document-node()
) as document-node()
{
    let $searchResult := $content
    let $docs := fn:doc($searchResult/search:result/@uri)
    return $docs
};
```

Installed transform using

```
curl --anyauth --user user:password -X PUT -d@"./add-attr.xqy" -H "Content-type: application/xquery" 'http://IP-ADD:port/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&trans:value=string\?'
```

Now, when I try to search for any string with transform like:

```
http://IP-ADD:port/v1/search?q=xyz&transform=add-attr
```

I get the following error:

```
<rapi:error 
xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <rapi:status-code>500</rapi:status-code>
  <rapi:status>INTERNAL ERROR</rapi:status>
  <rapi:message-code>XDMP-AS</rapi:message-code>
  <rapi:message>XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $service($context, $service-params, $input) -- Invalid coercion: ("{&amp;quot;root&amp;quot;:{&amp;quot;claim&amp;quot;:[{&amp;quot;type&amp;quot;:&amp;quot;In...", ",") as document-node().  See the MarkLogic server error log for further detail.</rapi:message>
</rapi:error>
```

I'm trying to convert each document into JSON from search result in transform function (I didn't include that code above). 
What do I miss? Where I'm wrong? Can you please help me out?

Thanks in advance,
Prithvi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transform receives the entire search:response in one call. That means that $searchResult/search:result/@uri XPath gives you one page's worth of URIs (probably ten). You are returning them as a sequence of documents when the return type expects just one. You need to provide a wrapper for them, so that you have just the one document. Something like:

```
document {
  fn:doc($content/search:result/@uri)
}
```

Also, it looks like you want to work with the full documents, not just snippets. You can get those by adding this to your REST search options:

```
<transform-results apply="raw"/>
```

Comment: A footnote:  ou can read the query result documents directly without a transform as documented in  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_65903

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to the fact that it is actually a text node, not a document node. if u want to fix this, you should probably change the expected parameter type to be an element node ( as element() ).

Comment: Yes, I figured that out and tried the same. while installing the transform I get this error:                  

    *RESTAPI-INVALIDCONTENT: (err:FOER0000) Invalid content: invalid add-attr extension: in transform function of add-attr extension,  returns element()? instead of document-node()? datatype; add-attr either is not a valid module or does not provide extension functions (transform) in the http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/add-attr*